# zWeatherFeed jquery include

Tags: jquery

On my site I include these jquery scripts:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jwplayer.js"></script>
```

I want to use zWeatherFeed : http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zweatherfeed/

I should include this code in my site header:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.zweatherfeed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But when I include jquery.min.js, some javascripts, for example: jscroll pane does not work, and the other problem is this:

In the body I insert:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

After loading site:

```
<div id="test" class="weatherFeed"></div> created but not load sub divs for example: 
   <div class="weatherItem odd day">
    <div class="weatherCity">... (city) ...</div>
    <div class="weatherCountry">... (country) ...</div>
    <div class="weatherTemp">... (temperature) ...</div>
    <div class="weatherDesc">... (condition) ...</div>
```

Comment: i solve this problem
i use yahoo city code for weather feed
after change this code to city weather code problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it without the jquery.min.js as you already include the full jquery.js from your storage ...

Comment: i try this but sub divs not load
i describ in secound section of question